How to remove "draw" for marks in "addplot" in tikz?
With tikz, when plot the points by \addplot, the draw=none doesn't work. What is the reason and how should I remove the black line around the point?
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ]
        \addplot [only marks, mark=*, mark options={fill=red,draw=none},mark size=5pt] coordinates {(2.47,-1.97)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I've left my original answer below as it is by far the simplest solution and will work well in most cases.
Simple, but not simplest:
You can create a custom plot mark by adapting example code from the PGF manual covering the creation of plot marks in PGF. For example,
\pgfdeclareplotmark{my plot mark}
{\pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0cm}{1ex}}{1ex}\pgfusepath{fill}}

This is a simple adaption of the examples on pages 755-757, which show how to create more standard marks. Then you can simply use my plot mark in place of * or diamond or whatever.

Full code:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfdeclareplotmark{my plot mark}
{\pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0cm}{1ex}}{1ex}\pgfusepath{fill}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[name=main,
    ]
    \addplot [only marks, mark=my plot mark, mark options={fill=red},mark size=5pt] coordinates {(2.47,-1.97)};
  \end{axis}
  \node[anchor=south west, align=center,draw,yshift=-.5\pgflinewidth,xshift=.5\pgflinewidth] at (main.south east) {%
    \textbf{hello} };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Simplest:
You can use draw=red.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ]
    \addplot [only marks, mark options={red},mark size=5pt] coordinates {(2.47,-1.97)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Explanation
The reason you cannot get rid of the drawing with e.g. draw=none is that marks are not especially flexible. They are rather designed to be simple and quick. If you don't like a mark as is, the answer is to use a different mark. Some marks have some minimal level of flexibility, such as customising the fill or stroke colour, but this is pretty minimal.
pgfplots basically uses pgf/tikz marks from either the plothandlers or plotmarks libraries. It provides a wrapper around these which performs some tasks to try to ensure reasonable output, but for the * mark, the code is essentially from pgf's plothandlers library, as far as I can tell.
Here's the code from pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex

% A stroke-filled circle mark

\pgfdeclareplotmark{*}
{%
\pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfqpoint{\pgfplotmarksize}{0sp}}{\pgfqpoint{0sp}{\pgfplotmarksize}}%
\pgfusepathqfillstroke
}%


The key command here is \pgfusepathqfillstroke. This strokes and fills the mark unconditionally. You can set the colours - and pgf provides a special facility to not fill some marks - but you can't stop it. If you use this mark, it is going to use this command because that's just how it is defined. This provides speed at the cost of flexibility, but that price is lowish because marks are easy to define and the benefit is highish because for plots involving hundreds of marks, efficient marks are important.
Interestingly, pgfplots.markers.code.tex actually includes some commented code relevant to this. Here's a snippet from the first part of the definition of the relevant handler, \pgfplots@markers@install@plotmark@handler:

% FIXME: using 'color=blue' will NOT activate filltrue!
% So: if 'tikz@mode' *contains* 'fillfalse', I know what to do...
% but all other cases are not clear
%--------------------------------------------------
% \iftikz@mode@draw
% \else
%       % Override the marker codes: force 'draw=none'
%       % even if the markers likes to be stroked:
%       \let\pgfusepathqfillstroke=\pgfusepathqfill
% \fi
% \iftikz@mode@fill
% \else
%       % Override the marker codes: force 'fill=none'
%       % even if the markers likes to be filled:
%       \let\pgfusepathqfillstroke=\pgfusepathqstroke
% \fi
%--------------------------------------------------


So it looks as if pgfplots either had or countenanced a strategy for making the marks responsive to directives switching off drawing, but that the code either never made it into a release version or got rolled back. This is possibly because the intervention caused unwanted side-effects, but you'd have to ask the developer why this is commented.
Note that enabling something like this would be much more complex - and hence much more liable to go pear-shaped - than using a custom mark.
[What's wrong with the shape of pears anyway?]

That is another way. But in some cases, the the draw will cause some troubles, for example, in spy environment. so is there a way to remove the draw?

Thanks. But why doesn't draw=none work in my example?

I have set this \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}.

@Y.zeng I added some explanation to my answer. I also found an interesting snippet in pgfplots.
